# List of indices (e.g., NDVI) that can be calculated with satellite images

Tags: imagery, ndvi, satellite, vegetation-index

I'm looking for a list of published indices that can be calculated from satellite images and the corresponding formula for each:

Some indicies, for example, would be:
 - NDVI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index
 - EVI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_vegetation_index
 - NDWI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_water_index

Here's one list I found:
http://spaceanalyzer.com/index.php/advanced-vegetation-index-avi

Is there a source that has a more comprehensive list segmented to domains (e.g., vegetation, water, buildings)? I can't seem to find a relevant resource.

Comment: I think [this site](https://www.indexdatabase.de/) has exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: 7 years later @Rodrigo hooks it up! What a great resource!